# When I click OK, the pop-up window is blank

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

```
public class CoolPool
{ 
public CoolPool()
{

}
public static void main(String[ ] args )
{
    Start start = new Start();
    //Table table = new Table();
}
} 


public class Start implements ActionListener 
{   
private static JFrame startF = new JFrame();
private static JPanel startP = new JPanel();
private static JButton start = new JButton("Start");
private static JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");

/*To create a window that then can be show on the screen.*/
public Start()
{
    startF.setContentPane(startP);
    startP.setLayout(null);
    start.setBounds(270,292,200,25);
    startP.add(exit);
    exit.setBounds(270,338,200,25);
    startP.add(start);
    start.addActionListener(this);
    exit.addActionListener(this);
    startF.setTitle("CoolPool");
    startF.setSize(750, 750);
    startF.setLocation(400, 100);
    startF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    startF.setVisible(true);
}


/*Design click button*/
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == start)
    {
        startF.setVisible(false);
        startF.dispose();          
        PlayerChoose pc = new PlayerChoose();
    }

    else if(e.getSource() == exit)
    {
        startF.setVisible(false);
        startF.dispose();
    }
}    

public JButton getStart()
{
    return start;
}

public JButton getExit()
{
    return exit;
}
}

public class PlayerChoose implements ActionListener 
{   
private static JFrame cF = new JFrame();
private static JPanel cP = new JPanel();
private static JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea("There will be two players participating in this game, ");
private static JTextArea textarea2 = new JTextArea("so we will randomly choose who comes first.");
private static JTextArea textarea3 = new JTextArea(" When you click the OK button, if the number shows 1,");
private static JTextArea textarea4 = new JTextArea(" Player1 (the clicker) first, and if it is 2, Player2 first.                                           ");
private static JButton OK = new JButton("OK");


/*To create a window that then can be show on the screen.*/
public PlayerChoose()
{
    cF.setContentPane(cP);
    cP.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    //OK.setBounds(300,342,200,25);
    cP.add(textarea);
    cP.add(textarea2);
    cP.add(textarea3);
    cP.add(textarea4);
    cP.add(OK);
    OK.addActionListener(this);
    cF.setTitle("CoolPool");
    cF.setSize(750, 150);
    cF.setLocation(400, 300);
    cF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    cF.setVisible(true);
}


/*Design click button*/
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == OK)
    {
        cF.setVisible(false);
        cF.dispose();
        Coin coin = new Coin();
        Table table = new Table();
    }
}    

public JButton getOK()
{
    return OK;
}
}

public class Coin implements ActionListener 
{
private static JFrame rF = new JFrame();
private static JPanel rP = new JPanel();
private static JButton close = new JButton("Close");
private static int coin;
private static JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea("                                           The number is                                       ");
private static JTextArea ta2 = new JTextArea("                                                 1                                             ");
private static JTextArea ta4 = new JTextArea("                                                 2                                             ");
private static JTextArea ta3 = new JTextArea("                                           Player 1 first                                      ");
private static JTextArea ta5 = new JTextArea("                                           Player 2 first                                      ");

public Coin()
{
    setCoin();
    rF.setContentPane(rP);
    rP.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    rP.add(ta1);
    if(coin == 1)
    {
        rP.add(ta2);
        rP.add(ta3);
    }
    else if(coin == 2)
    {
        rP.add(ta4);
        rP.add(ta5);
    } 

    rP.add(close);
    close.addActionListener(this);
    rF.setTitle("CoolPool");
    rF.setSize(200, 200);
    rF.setLocation(50, 300);
    rF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    rF.setVisible(true);
}

public static int setCoin()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int num = r.nextInt(2);
    num = num + 1;
    coin = num;
    return coin; 
}

    /*Design click button*/
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == close)
        {
            rF.setVisible(false);
            rF.dispose();
        }
    }   
    }

public class Table
{
private static GameArena ga = new GameArena(886,528);
private static Text words = new Text("Welcome to CoolPool v1.0",14,29,15,"WHITE",1);
private static Text player1 = new Text("Player 1:",10,29,456,"WHITE",1);
private static Text player2 = new Text("Player 2:",10,29,476,"RED",1);
private static Rectangle g = new Rectangle(58,57,712,356,"GREEN",1);
private static Rectangle l = new Rectangle(205,57,1,356,"WHITE",1);
private static Ball b[] = {new Ball(58,57,44,"BLACK",2),new Ball(58,413,44,"BLACK",2),new Ball(770,57,44,"BLACK",2),new Ball(770,413,44,"BLACK",2),
                           new Ball(414,57,44,"BLACK",2),new Ball(414,413,44,"BLACK",2),new Ball(205,235,4,"WHITE",2)};
private static Rectangle r = new Rectangle(29,29,29,412,"GREY",4);
private static Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(29,29,770,28,"GREY",4);
private static Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(29,413,770,28,"GREY",4);
private static Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(770,29,29,412,"GREY",4);

private static Iballs ib = new Iballs(ga);
private static Line wl;
private static boolean exist = false;
private static boolean clicked = false;
private static Rectangle rr;

public Table()
{ 
    ga.addText(words);
    ga.addText(player1);
    ga.addText(player2);
    ga.addRectangle(g);
    ga.addRectangle(l);
    ga.addBall(b[0]);
    ga.addBall(b[1]);
    ga.addBall(b[2]);
    ga.addBall(b[3]);
    ga.addBall(b[4]);
    ga.addBall(b[5]);
    ga.addBall(b[6]);
    ga.addRectangle(r);
    ga.addRectangle(r1);
    ga.addRectangle(r2);
    ga.addRectangle(r3);
    game_Go();
}

public static void drawLine()
{
    wl = new Line(ib.getWx(),ib.getWy(),ga.getMousePositionX(),ga.getMousePositionY(),1,"WHITE",4);
    ga.addLine(wl);            
}

public static void drawRedrectangle()
{
    double rLength = wl.getLength() * 2;
    if (rLength >= 412)
    {
        rLength = 412;
    }
    rr = new Rectangle(828, 29, 29, rLength, "RED", 4);
    ga.addRectangle(rr);

}

public static void game_Go()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if (ga.leftMousePressed() == true)
        {
            if (ib.ckWhite() == true)
            { 
                exist = true;
                clicked = true;   
            }
            else if (clicked == true)
            {
                cSpeed();
                clicked = false;
                exist = false;
            }
        }
        if (exist == true)
        {
            drawLine();
            drawRedrectangle();
        }
        ga.pause();
        ib.changePosition();
        ga.removeLine(wl);
        ga.removeRectangle(rr);

    }
}

public static void cSpeed()
{
    ib.wbSpeed((wl.getXStart() - wl.getXEnd())/7, (wl.getYStart() - wl.getYEnd())/7);
}

public GameArena getGa()
{
    return ga;
}
}
```

When I click the start button in the Start window, it will jump to the PlayerChoose window. Then I click the OK button. At this time, the table window and the Coin window should pop up at the same time, but the problem now is that the two windows that pop up are blank. I have checked that if you don't open the table window and only open the Coin window, the Coin window that pops up will be normal. And if the table window is placed in the main of CoolPool, it is normal. Therefore, I want to know why the two windows opened at this time are blank.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6efwa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ref9c.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRc1E.png)

Comment: This might not be the problem, but basically you should never `startP.setLayout(null);` and try to do the layout yourself with setBounds.  Just don't.  Use a layout manager and it'll be easier.  Replace all of that with a layout manager I don't want to do your math to see if the components are outside the window or something.

Comment: Thanks,but I am sure all the components are in the window.

Comment: *"I am sure all the components are in the window."* Good for you! I'm sure this question will get more attention once you stop ignoring sound advice. I agree fully with @markspace, and given 'lack of layouts' is likely contributing to the problem, not even going to bother to try running the code until it uses layouts (and still has the problem).